# How to differentiate microsoft teams channel folder and normal SP folder in sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get the Microsoft Teams channel's folders using SharePoint rest API, but i'm getting all folders in the document library. How to differentiate  b/w MS-Teams channel's folder and normal SP folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in Share Point folder which are create for channels. Only way for you to identify folder would be to match channel names but it's not reliable as when channel name is changed SharePoint folder name does not change.